# What do the 16 definable colors in .Xresources do?

Tags: xorg, colors, xterm

I've found an endless supply of themes availble online that use hex-color codes to change how X windows display, but I can't find any documentation that clearly states what each color does.  For instance, in my .Xresources file:

```
*color0:     #000000
*color1:     #e59400
*color2:     #00cc00
*color3:     #00cc00
*color4:     #005500
*color5:     #e59400
*color6:     #00cc00
*color7:     #00cc00
*color8:     #000000
*color9:     #e59400
*color10:    #e59400
*color11:    #e59400
*color12:    #005500
*color13:    #e59400
*color14:    #e59400
*color15:    #00cc00
```

I know how to change each 'color' but I don't know what each one is actually changing, in other words...which color goes to what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are used in `xterm`.  They define a color palette. Colors 0-7 are the eight "ANSI" colors.  For colors 8-15, it is more complicated:

- xterm can be told to display text which is bold, using colors (the `boldColors` resource—see [manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html)).  It does this as an alternative to using bold fonts because some bitmap fonts are available as bold only by overstriking the font offset by one pixel -- not always readable (this is configurable using the `boldFont` resource).
- xterm also uses the same colors for implementing the aixterm 16-color control sequence (which is unrelated to the bold video attribute).

The manual also lists the default values for the colors as names.  X maps the names to RGB values.  Those hex-color codes are one way of representing RGB (red/green/blue) using two hexadecimal digits for each color.  You may also see that represented in the format `rbg:rr/gg/bb`.

Some programs assume that color0 is the same as the background color and color7 is the same as the foreground (text) color.  Actually, xterm maintains *those* colors with a separate set of default values (the `-fg` and `-bg` command-line options for instance).

Comment: I wondered if that was the case but didn't have the data to be 100% sure.  Thanks!